# Getting null in Result on sending soap request

Tags: android, soap

i am doing parsing using SOAP webservices. When i am hitting the request it is returning me null. Please help

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(Const.NAMESPACE, Const.METHOD_FOR_GETBRAND_NAME);

/*PropertyInfo mobileAppLogin = new PropertyInfo();
mobileAppLogin.setName("mobileAppLogin");
mobileAppLogin.setValue(Const.MOBILE_APP_LOGIN);
mobileAppLogin.setType(String.class);
request.addProperty(mobileAppLogin);

PropertyInfo  mobileAppTransKey= new PropertyInfo();
mobileAppTransKey.setName("mobileAppTransKey");
mobileAppTransKey.setValue(Const.MOBILE_API_TRANS_KEY);
mobileAppTransKey.setType(String.class);
request.addProperty(mobileAppTransKey);*/

request.addProperty("mobileAppLogin",Const.MOBILE_APP_LOGIN);
request.addProperty("mobileAppTransKey",Const.MOBILE_API_TRANS_KEY);


SoapSerializationEnvelope envelopes = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER12);
envelopes.dotNet = true;
envelopes.setOutputSoapObject(request);

   Log.e("REQUEST... ","-----------" + request);

HttpTransportSE mHttpTransportSE = new HttpTransportSE(Const.URL_SOAP_ACTION_FOR_GET_BRAND_NAME);
mHttpTransportSE.debug = true;
try {
    mHttpTransportSE.call(Const.SOAP_ACTION, envelopes);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

try {
    result = (SoapPrimitive) envelopes.getResponse();


} catch (SoapFault soapFault) {
    soapFault.printStackTrace();
}
results = result.toString();
String p = results;
Log.e("Service get brand name result result... " ,"---------"+ results);
```

Comment: The response is null? Did you try the url in a browser?

Comment: yes its returning the response

Comment: Compare your request envelope with wsdl. Is it the same?